# Prevent form submission with Semantic-Ui

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation, semantic-ui

I'm working with [Semantic Ui Forms](http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html) but I can't figure out how to prevent form submission after form validation. 
I can't find anything in their documentation… thanks a lot.

This is my current submission script:

```
    $(function () {
    $('#formId').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'phpScriptUrl.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          //"ok" label on success.
          $('#successLabel').css("display", "block");
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: I assume you're applying the required classes to your submit button: `ui submit`? If so. you're likely looking for the validation callbacks, explained here: http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html#callbacks . Whatever it is you want to do after form validation, you can use `onSuccess` and `onFailure` to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using callbacks. I added some form validation as example

```
$('.ui.form').form({
    fields: {
      firstname     : 'empty',
      lastname   : 'empty'
    },
    onSuccess: function(event, fields) {
        event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'phpScriptUrl.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          //"ok" label on success.
          $('#successLabel').css("display", "block");
        }
      });      
    }
  })
;
```